# Remove the first pagenumber on a maketitle with pdfpage

Tags: titles, page-numbering, pdfpages

I found a solution to overlay a text on a included pdf page using pdfpages package. I wanted to add a maketitle on this pdf page, and I finally did it. But I do not know how to get rid of this pagenumber.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Title}        
\date{Date}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true, pages=1,
     pagecommand=\vspace*{3cm}{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}]
             {file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\thispagestyle{empty}` as part of the `pagecommand`, since `\maketitle` would issue `\thispagestyle{plain}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Title}
\date{Date}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[
  fitpaper=true, 
  pages=1,
  pagecommand=\vspace*{3cm}{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}}]
  {lipsum50.pdf}

\end{document}
```